# Address Sanitizer: "SEGV on unknown adress" when using throw-catch and printf

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, address-sanitizer

When I throw something, e.g. an int or a char const*, and use printf to inspect the error, I get an Address Sanitizer Error.

I wasn't able to find anything similar on the net and my code example is so basic that i really do not understand how it could possibly create an error.

Reduced Code Sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    try {
        throw 42;
    } catch (int msg) {
        printf("%d\n", msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Console Output when running the code:

```
ASAN:SIGSEGV
=================================================================
==16533==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f3eb9c1a76c bp 0x7ffde2b6fde0 sp 0x7ffde2b6fdd0 T0)
#0 0x7f3eb9c1a76b (/home/[...]/build/test/sample+0xc476b)
#1 0x7f3eb7e38b44 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b44)
#2 0x7f3eb9c1a5d9 (/home/[...]/build/test/sample+0xc45d9)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV ??:0 ??
==16533==ABORTING
```

When disabling -fsanitize flags, Valgrind gives the following hints:

```
==18103== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18103== Command: ./build/test/sample
==18103== 
==18103== Invalid read of size 4
==18103==    at 0x109205: main (sample.cpp:11)
==18103==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18103== 
==18103== 
==18103== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18103==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==18103==    at 0x109205: main (sample.cpp:11)
==18103==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==18103==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==18103==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==18103==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==18103==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==18103== 
==18103== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18103==     in use at exit: 148 bytes in 2 blocks
==18103==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 148 bytes allocated
==18103== 
==18103== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18103==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18103==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18103==      possibly lost: 132 bytes in 1 blocks
==18103==    still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==18103==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18103== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==18103== 
==18103== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18103== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Compiler settings: Using clang 3.5.0-10 on Debian Jessie with following flags (excerpt from Makefile):

```
CXX:=clang++

## generic warning-related stuff
WARNFLAGS:=-Wall -Wextra -Wextra-semi -pedantic
WARNFLAGS+= -Wsign-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32
WARNFLAGS+= -Werror
## generic debugging-related stuff
DEBUGFLAGS:=-O2 -g3 -ggdb -fno-omit-frame-pointer
## harden program by performing additional checks
SANITIZER:=-fsanitize=address,signed-integer-overflow,shift,bool,bounds,vptr,integer-divide-by-zero,float-cast-overflow,float-divide-by-zero,enum
HARDENCXXFLAGS:=-ftrapv -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DDEBUG=1 -UNDEBUG -fstack-protector-all -fPIE -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wformat-nonliteral $(SANITIZER)
## C++ compiler flags
DEF += -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
CXXFLAGS:=$(WARNFLAGS) -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++14 -maes $(DEBUGFLAGS) $(HARDENCXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDEFLAGS) $(DEF) -Xclang -fcolor-diagnostics
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just note: you cann't use `valgrind` and `sanitize` instrumentation at the same time, to get valid output from `valgrind`, rebuild you app without `-fsanitize`

Comment: with `clang` `3.7` it print 42 without crash.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea what causes Address Sanitizer to complain with clang 3.5 in such a basic code sample?

Comment: May you use untested combination of compile flags, try from scratch remove all your compilation flags and compile with just `-fsanitize=address`

Comment: this works. I'm going through the compile flags now to find out which triggered the info. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, turns out the problem appears only after linking against a file that has lines like `std::cerr << "Error message" << std::endl;` - removing those lines makes the Address Sanitizer Error disappear. I still don't understand why, though, because these lines will never be accessed by my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem appears only after linking against a file that has lines like `std::cerr << "Error message" << std::endl;` - removing those lines makes the Address Sanitizer Error disappear.

Digging deeper, it appears to be an issue either with usage of virtual functions and/or with a specific combination of compile flags.

To see the isolated Problem, see [AddressSanitizer / LeakSanitizer Error with -lsupc++ and -stdlib=libc++ on a never called virtual function that writes to a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857672/adresssanitizer-leaksanitizer-error-with-lsupc-and-stdlib-libc-on-a-neve)