# AddressSanitizer / LeakSanitizer Error with -lsupc++ and -stdlib=libc++ on a never called virtual function that writes to a stream

Tags: c++, compilation, libraries, clang++, address-sanitizer

The following code throws an **AddressSanitizer Error** when compiled on Debian Jessie with clang 3.5.

It appears to be related to the combination of linked libraries, but i have not been able to find something similar on the internet.

### Reproduction of the Error

Invocation: `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -fsanitize=address,vptr sample.cpp -lsupc++ -o sample`

```
//sample.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    virtual void bar() {
        std::cerr << std::endl;
    }
public:
    virtual ~Foo() { }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    try{
        throw 1;
    } catch(int i) {
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When omitting compile flag `-lc++abi`, a **LeakSanitizer Runtime Error** occurs instead.

When omitting any of the other compile flags, **no Error** occurs.

What causes the error? Is something wrong with my code or is this an invalid combination of compile flags, and if so, what is causing the conflict?